# Add 1 hour to time from user input

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime

I'm coding a script that asks the user for a time (24 hour format), and then adding 1 hour to the inputted time. Later on in my script, I add the time that it gives out onto a webpage for my testing.

Here is my code. (*`Time_inp` is the new time that 1 hour has been added to from input time*)

```
import webbrowser
import pyautogui
import datetime
from datetime import timedelta

Time_inp = int(input("Enter a time (+1hour will be added to it): "))
date_time_str = Time_inp
date_time_obj = datetime.strptime(date_time_str, '%H%H:%M%M')
finalDate = date_time_obj + timedelta(hours=1)
```

Later in script:

```
# inputting new time from earlier
pyautogui.moveTo(859, 576, 1)
time.sleep(1)
pyautogui.click()
pyautogui.hotkey('ctrl', 'a')
pyautogui.typewrite(Time_inp)
pyautogui.press('enter')
time.sleep(2)
```

I'm not sure how to make it type out the new time (from adding 1 hour to input time) onto the webpage. I've tried a method, but lost the progress.

Comment: For starters `'%H%H:%M%M'` is wrong — should be just `'%H:%M'`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set actually set Time_inp to the new time. Or instead of time_inp into the typewrite method, pass in finalDate.

```
Time_inp = int(input("Enter a time (+1hour will be added to it): "))
Time_inp = datetime.strptime(Time_inp , '%H:%M')
Time_inp = Time_inp + timedelta(hours=1)
Time_inp = Time_inp.strftime('%H:%M')
```

Comment: I think this is basically the right idea, but `Time_inp` + the `timedelta` needs to be converted back to a string for outputting (using `strftime()`). I also think the `'%H%H:%M%M'` is the wrong format string.

Comment: adding the strftime, yeah %H%H is not valid for the date time formatting. Easy link here for help on that. https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/datetime/strftime. The basic structure should get them going in the right direction.

Comment: `'%H%m'` isn't correct, either.

Comment: @martineau did you downvote because the time format specifically is incorrect? The user should be able to research to find the correct date time format. The structure of the answer is correct and solves the users problem, what is the issue?

Comment: Yes, that is why I down-voted, the code currently in your answer is incorrect. Sure, theoretically the OP could fix it — they should have done that before asking their question — that's not the point and IMO they shouldn't have accepted your answer for that reason.

Comment: @martineau the date time strings have been updated